# mysql create select results from two separate queries

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a sql query that creates a league table with the headings team name, games played, total points scored and average points per game.

The query for games played is: 
SELECT `team_name`, 
COUNT(*) AS games_played
FROM `fixtures`
GROUP BY `team_name`;

The query for the total points scored is: 
SELECT  `teams`.`team_name`, 
COUNT( * ) AS total_points_gained
FROM `scores`,`players`,`teams`
WHERE `scores`.`player_id`=`players`.`player_id`
AND `players`.`team_name` = `teams`.`team_name`
GROUP BY `teams`.`team_name`

How can I combine the two queries to get all the data in one result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```sql
SELECT teams.team_name, COUNT(*) AS total_points_gained,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fixtures WHERE fixtures.team_name = teams.team_name) AS games_played 
FROM scores,players,teams 
WHERE scores.player_id=players.player_id 
AND players.team_name = teams.team_name 
GROUP BY teams.team_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about JOINs. With a JOIN you can combine those two querys for example by team_name into one result.